# Media and Data Integrity Errors

Tags: hardware, solid-state-drive

I was wondering if anyone can tell me what these mean. From most people posting about them, there is no more than double digits. However, I have 1051556645921812989870080 Media and Data Integrity Errors on my SK hynix PC711 on my new HP dev one. Thanks!

Here's my entire smartctl output

```
`smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.0.7-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number: SK hynix PC711 HFS001TDE9X073N
Serial Number: KDB3N511010503A37
Firmware Version: HPS0
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID: 0x1c5c
IEEE OUI Identifier: 0xace42e
Total NVM Capacity: 1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity: 0
Controller ID: 1
NVMe Version: 1.3
Number of Namespaces: 1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity: 1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size: 512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64: ace42e 00254f98f1
Local Time is: Wed Nov 9 13:58:37 2022 EST
Firmware Updates (0x16): 3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x001f): Security Format Frmw_DL NS_Mngmt Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f): Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x1e): Cmd_Eff_Lg Ext_Get_Lg Telmtry_Lg Pers_Ev_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size: 64 Pages
Warning Comp. Temp. Threshold: 84 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold: 85 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x02): NA_Fields

Supported Power States
St Op Max Active Idle RL RT WL WT Ent_Lat Ex_Lat
0 + 6.3000W - - 0 0 0 0 5 5
1 + 2.4000W - - 1 1 1 1 30 30
2 + 1.9000W - - 2 2 2 2 100 100
3 - 0.0500W - - 3 3 3 3 1000 1000
4 - 0.0040W - - 3 3 3 3 1000 9000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt Data Metadt Rel_Perf
0 + 512 0 0
1 - 4096 0 0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning: 0x00
Temperature: 34 Celsius
Available Spare: 100%
Available Spare Threshold: 5%
Percentage Used: 0%
Data Units Read: 13,162,025 [6.73 TB]
Data Units Written: 3,846,954 [1.96 TB]
Host Read Commands: 156,458,059
Host Write Commands: 128,658,566
Controller Busy Time: 116
Power Cycles: 273
Power On Hours: 126
Unsafe Shutdowns: 15
Media and Data Integrity Errors: 1051556645921812989870080
Error Information Log Entries: 0
Warning Comp. Temperature Time: 0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time: 0
Temperature Sensor 1: 34 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2: 36 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
No Errors Logged`
```

Comment: I wrote you an answer to your question below, but want to ask you a question, as well. Have you experienced any actual errors or data corruption before or after you saw the large `Media and Data Integrity Errors` value from `smartctl`?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar SMART reading from the same model.

I'm seeing a reported `Media and Data Integrity Errors` rate of a value that's over `2 ^ 84`.

It could just be an error with its SMART implementation or the utility reading from it.

Converting your reported value of `1051556645921812989870080` to hex, we get `0xdead0000000000000000` big endian and `0x0000000000000000adde` little endian.

Similarly, when I convert my value to hex, I get `0xffff0000000000000000` big endian and `0x0000000000000000ffff` little endian, where `f` is just denotes a value other than `0`.

I'm going to assume that the `Media and Data Integrity Errors` value has no actual meaning with regard to real errors. I doubt that *both* of us would have values that are padded with 16 `0`'s when converted to hex. Something is sending/receiving/parsing bad data.

If you poke around the other reported SMART values in your post, and on my end, some of them don't seem to make much sense, either.